# How can I give the Facebook App access to the Facebook Page via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-messenger-bot

As we all know, inside the [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) interface, you can add Facebook Pages to a Facebook App as in the picture below and generate the `Page Access Token`.

[image]

I'm trying to do this programmatically via the API requests. Unfortunately, I did not find in the documentation of the request how to do this.

*What have I done so far?*

- I can get the `User ID` and `User Access Token` via `Facebook Login` ([Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)).
- I can get the list of `Facebook Pages` that a person owns. In the response, I have the `Page ID` and the `Page Access Token` ([Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/user/accounts)).
- I have the Facebook app that is in development mode. That app has `App ID` and `App Secret`. With these values, I can get the `App Access Token` ([Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)).
- I can set `Webhook` to the Facebook App with `App ID` and `App Access Token` ([Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/app/subscriptions)).
- I can set the `Webhook Subscriptions Fields` for my Facebook App ([Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps)).

**Question:** What kind of API request should I use to add a Facebook Page to the Facebook App?

[image]

The list of my requests:

1. I take `Page ID` and `Page Access Token` with this GET request cause this request returns the list of `Facebook Pages` that a person owns:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/%7Buser-id%7D/accounts?access_token=%7Buser-access-token%7D)

2. I set the `Webhook` in my `Facebook App` with this `POST` request:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{app-id}/subscriptions?access_token={app-access-token}&callback_url={url-address}&verify_token={verify-token}&object=page&include_values=true](https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/%7Bapp-id%7D/subscriptions?access_token=%7Bapp-access-token%7D&callback_url=%7Burl-address%7D&verify_token=%7Bverify-token%7D&object=page&include_values=true)

It successfully works and I see this Webhook in the "Webhooks" block of the `Dashboard` interface.

3. Then I make this POST request to set `Webhook Subscriptions Fields`:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,message_deliveries,message_reads,messaging_payments,messaging_pre_checkouts,messaging_checkout_updates,messaging_account_linking,messaging_referrals,message_echoes,messaging_game_plays,standby,messaging_handovers,messaging_policy_enforcement,message_reactions,inbox_labels&access_token={page-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage-id%7D/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,message_deliveries,message_reads,messaging_payments,messaging_pre_checkouts,messaging_checkout_updates,messaging_account_linking,messaging_referrals,message_echoes,messaging_game_plays,standby,messaging_handovers,messaging_policy_enforcement,message_reactions,inbox_labels&access_token=%7Bpage-access-token%7D)

In this request, I use `Page ID` and `Page Access Token` from the first step.

Unfortunately, I have such an error message:

> To subscribe to the messages field, one of these permissions is
> needed: pages_messaging

Comment: If you were able to generate pages access tokens already, then what more do you expect to happen now? What else do you think “adding” a page there would actually do?

Comment: @CBroe Hello! As I said before I can get the list of Facebook Pages that a person owns. In the response, I have the [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/user/accounts), but that's not enough. You need to link the Facebook App to the Facebook Page. In the future, through the Facebook App, I want to manage all the conversations that users write to the Facebook Page via Facebook Messenger. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What else, other than subscribing to webhooks updates, do you actually need for that then?

Comment: @CBroe Maybe I don't fully understand something. In my post, you can see the first screenshot. It's "Access Token" block in "Facebook Messenger" product of my Facebook App. As you can see it's empty. As I understand it's mean that my Facebook App don't have any connections with any Facebook Pages. If customers write to my Facebook Page, my Facebook App will not know about it. Since there is no connection between the Facebook Page and the Facebook App. Isn't that right? Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: _“If customers write to my Facebook Page, my Facebook App will not know about it.”_ - for your app to be notified, you need to subscribe to updates from the page via webhooks. And how to do that via API, is explained in the last two documentation links you yourself already posted.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your patience. Could you please check my post again?! At the end of the post, I added detailed steps. What did I miss?

Comment: Sounds like you simply did not ask the page admin user for the mentioned permission, when you made them login to get the user token.

Comment: @CBroe Tell me, please. Where are these permission configured? I see that in the `Facebook App`, we can connect `Facebook Login` product. Please direct me in the right direction.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been following down a similar rabbit hole. Indeed, Facebook documentation is confusing, but it ended up being pretty simple. Here is the modified [Facebook Login example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/), which gets page access token and then adds necessary webhook subscriptions for page messaging. After you've run it, you will see the page is added to the App settings with the requested webhook subscriptions. Hope it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let page_access_token = null
      let page_id = null

      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
        console.log('statusChangeCallback')
        console.log(response) // The current login status of the person.
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
          testAPI()
        } else {
          // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Please log ' + 'into this webpage.'
        }
      }

      function checkLoginState() {
        // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          // See the onlogin handler
          statusChangeCallback(response)
        })
      }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
          cookie: true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
          xfbml: true, // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
          version: 'v12.0', // Use this Graph API version for this call.
        })

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
          statusChangeCallback(response) // Returns the login status.
        })
      }

      // add webhooks to page subscriptions
      function addPageSubscriptions() {
        FB.api(
          `/${page_id}/subscribed_apps`,
          'POST',
          {
            subscribed_fields: [
              'messages',
              // any other webhook event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook/#events
            ],
            access_token: page_access_token,
          },
          function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
              console.log({ response })
            } else {
              console.error(response.error)
            }
          },
        )
      }

      // pages I have access to
      function getPages() {
        FB.api('/me/accounts', function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log({ response })
            page_access_token = response.data[0].access_token
            page_id = response.data[0].id

            addPageSubscriptions()
          } else {
            console.error(response.error)
          }
        })
      }

      function testAPI() {
        // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ')

        // Me
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
          console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name)
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!'

          getPages()
        })
      }
    </script>

    <!-- The JS SDK Login Button -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: Define the scopes for managing pages metadata and pages_messaging for the webhooks -->

    <fb:login-button
      scope="public_profile,email,pages_manage_metadata,pages_messaging"
      onlogin="checkLoginState();"
    >
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status"></div>

    <!-- Load the JS SDK asynchronously -->
    <script
      async
      defer
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a related/similar issue to OP.  I am trying to find a way in the AppID settngs to specific what page(s) the AppID has access to.  So when the login prompt asks the user "what pages does this have access to" it will only list the pages that are defined in the AppID.  But this doesn't appear possible.  I already have an instance where my clients need to create Post1 to go to Page1, Post2 needs to go Post2, etc.  But if they login and accidentally assign Page1 and Page2 to the login, then all posts will go to Page1 and Page2.

Comment: I suppose I will have to track which pages are permitted for that AppID, then when the user tries to post I have to do a PopUp asking them which pages to post to.